# Change value with external script

Tags: python, winapi, memory, cheat-engine

I created a Python script that returns a value that changes quickly in an online game, so I need to auto-populate the value in Cheat Engine and hit search.[image]

Are there such plugins in Cheat Engine or similar programs. If not, how can I upgrade Cheat Engine? [GitHub](https://github.com/cheat-engine/cheat-engine)